# Stripe Order API and Product API

Tags: paypal, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment

Is it possible to use the Stripe [Orders API](https://stripe.com/docs/orders) without using Stripe's payments API? I've managed to create some sample products and create an order and invoke the payment related method with a sample token. This all works, but in a live environment I'm not clear what would happen? The orders and products APIs are very useful but because Stripe can't be used with PayPal, we can't use it as the provider for payments...

Comment: What is your primary use case for Stripe Orders API if you are not using it for Payment ?

Comment: To track orders and inventory. The Orders API automatically manages inventory level when an order's status is set to paid for example. This is useful functionality without which I'll need to roll my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Test cards](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards) won't work in live mode, so the API would return a [`card_error`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#errors) when you try to [pay an order](https://stripe.com/docs/api#pay_order).

Comment: Thanks Ywain! So I guess these APIs can't possibly be used separately then unless there's any other way of marking an order as 'paid'?